# How can I get the full list of running processes on a Mac from a python app

Tags: python, macos, process

I want to get the list of running processes on the Mac, similar to what you get from 'ps -ea'

I have tried ﻿**os.popen('ps -ea')** but this only lists a small subset of the processes, presumably those owned by the owning shell.

Other options I have tried are

```
'sh -c /bin/ps -ea'
'bash -c /bin/ps -ea'
'csh -c /bin/ps -ea'
Running as root via sudo
data = subprocess.Popen(['ps','ea'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.readlines()
```

What other methods are there that might give me the full process information listing?

This is for a wx python app to monitor specific processes and spot when they die.

Comment: you can try the subprocess module if your Python version is 2.4++. just curious, why do you want to do this in Python.?

Comment: I do get the same output when calling ps -ea from the terminal or using os.popen('ps -ea'). Are you sure you're reading the file object completely ?

Comment: os.popen('ps aux') gives me the full list, os.popen('ps ea') gives me a minimal list, so I'm pretty sure I am

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`os.popen('ps aux')` looks like it's listing all processes for me.

Comment: and it does for me too! Thanks.

Comment: Try using `subprocess.Popen` -- it's the preferred approach.

Comment: data = subprocess.Popen(['ps','aux'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.readlines() works just as well